# Calling scrollTo() in onAppear() doesn't always work

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview, onappear

See example code below:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                List {
                    ForEach(1...30, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text("\(item)")
                        .id(item)
                    }
                }
                .onAppear {
                    proxy.scrollTo(8, anchor: .topLeading)
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("test") {
                TestView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Two observations:

1. If I don't put the `TestView` in `NavigationLink` (for example, put it directly in `ContentView`), the code works fine.
2. The following diff works around the issue:

   ```
                     .onAppear {
    -                    proxy.scrollTo(8, anchor: .topLeading)
    +                    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
    +                        proxy.scrollTo(8, anchor: .topLeading)
    +                    }
                     }
   ```

Does anyone know what's the root cause? The workaround suggests it's a timing issue, which explains my observation 1, where there is no navigation animation. So, is it because, when the `onAppear()` is run, the animation is still ongoing and hence `proxy.scrollTo()` fails silently? But if so, shouldn't Apple provide a version of `onAppear()` which is run after animation is done? The current workaround looks too hacky. I found it on the net and there are different versions, some using `async()`, some using `asyncAfter()`, which suggests none is reliable.

Comment: this is a common thing with `onAppear`, SwiftUI is still young, maybe we will get a better version of this in June. Submit a bug report, it might help push apple to provide something.

Comment: It is a timing issue. `.onAppear` is called BEFORE the view is shown on screen.  It is more akin to a `viewWillAppear`. Therefore, there is nothing to animate at that point. Personally, I have found that using `.asyncAfter()` with a delay works better, but YMMV. You will see the same issue when trying to sequence animations. You have to have the timing right, or something won't fire properly. Personally, I would love to see a sequential animation queue we could use, but currently that is not available.

Comment: Thanks all for the confirmation and explanation. I'll submit a bug soon.

Comment: I had a similar issue. But on watchOS I couldn't find any workaround it works only on iOS and macOS